# How to deploy a Dart Polymer app to Javascript using dart2js

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dart-pub, dart2js

I got a problem while deploying Dart code using Polymer to Javascript. I've created a polymer application with DartEditor and made a simple example. This example works in Dartium but when I try to build it as a Polymer App (in Javascript) and launch it, the app fails.

How am I supposed to convert a Dart Polymer app to Javascript ?

Here's the example code I made that fails :

example.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>

    <link rel="import" href="example-polymer.html">
    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div is="example-polymer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

example-polymer.html

```html
<polymer-element name="example-polymer" extends="div">
  <template>
    <div>
      <input on-change="{{ change }}"/><br>
      <span>Text : {{ text }}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="example-polymer.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

example-polymer.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('example-polymer')
class ExampleBolymer extends DivElement with Polymer, Observable {
  @published String text = "" ;

  ExampleBolymer.created() : super.created() {
  }

  void change(Event e, var detail , InputElement target) {
    text = target.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/example.html
```

to your pubspec.yaml
and call

```bash
pub build
```

Your files should be in the `web` directory of your package.

Comment: It is "generating" files to "out" directory. And after compiling to JS, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you run it from the DartEditor or did you run `dart2js`?
AFAIK DartEditor's menues to start dart2js are not up-to-date (WIP).
I had the best experience calling `pub build` or `pub build --mode=debug` in the command line in the package root directory.

Comment: I think this is a known problem. `pub build` fails if you have files in you web directory from a previous `run as JavaScript` like that with the extension `.bootstrap.dart`. Please remove all generated files form your `web` directory or the entire `web/out` directory if it exists and run `pub build` again.