# Questions on using dart without dart editor

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart2js

I'm trying to get dart working. As editor I want to use emacs dart-mode. I've got 2 questions concerning using dart without the dart editor:

1) Do I manually need to call dart2js or does the in html included script dart.js do that for me? Where can I find the dart.js file on a linux system?

2) Where can I find the packages that come with the dart install on a linux system?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`dart.js` is contained in the [browser package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser). Once you have added this package to *pubspec.yaml* and run `pub install` you can add the script file to your html.

```html
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

Assuming you have downloaded the dart bundle you will find all the binaries under `$DART_HOME/dart-sdk/bin`.

Comment: Do I still need to call dart2js manually even if I included dart.js?

Comment: Yes, `dart.js` will only check if the DartVM is available and replace `*.dart` with `*.dart.js` if not there.

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to call `dart2js` or `pub build` for generating JS from Dart

More information about generating Javascript [Dart Package Management via dart2js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718955/dart-package-management-via-dart2js)

2) This depends how you installed Dart.
I installed by just unpacking the downloaded archiv which contains

```
install-dir
|- dart-sdk
  |- lib
    |- async
    |- collection
    |- ...
  |- bin
    |- dart
    |- dart2js
    |- dartanalyzer
    |- pub
    |- ...
```